# Grouping cities, states and countries in MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, group-by

I am new to PHP and have visited several sites for this but can't seem to understand thoroughly.

I have this query:

```
$result = mysql_query
  ("SELECT Country, State, City
       FROM Address_Base
       ORDER BY Country, State, City")
  or die(mysql_error());
```

This gives the following data sample:

> Canada - State 1 - City Apple
>
> Canada - State 2 - City Grapes
>
> Canada - State 1 - City Apple
>
> Canada - State 2 - City Coffee
>
> USA - State 1 - City Zebra
>
> USA - State 2 - City Cat
>
> USA - State 2 - City Lion
>
> USA - State 3 - City Bird
>
> USA - State 1 - City Zebra

My goal is to group the cities under the respective state and count city, group the states under the respective country & group similar countries and produce something like this

```
Canada -
{
  State 1 - City Apple (2)
  State 2 - City Coffee (1), City Grapes (1)
}

USA -
{
    State 1 - City Zebra (2)
    State 2 - City Cat (1), City Lion (1)
    State 3 - City Bird (1)
}
```

From some other site, I got this:

```
$combinedResults = array();

while ($rec=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $combinedResults[$rec['Country']][] = array
            (               
                'S' => $rec['State'], 
                'C' => $rec['City']
            );                           
}

foreach(array_keys($combinedResults) as $Country)
{ 
    echo '<div class="country">'.$Country.'</div>';

    foreach($combinedResults[$Country] as $Set)
    { 
        echo $Set['S'].'<br/>'.$Set['C'].'<br/><br/>'; 
    } 
}
```

This only groups similar Countries and not states and the cities. I guess the above piece of code is trying to pre-process the data in some sort of multi-dimensional array and have a for loop display the results. I am not able to understand it clearly.

I would be very thankful if someone could explain it for me and how I can further group the states and cities respectively as sought above?

Answer (score 1):

SQL queries will give you a set of results with a fixed number of columns. Your example has a variable number of columns (multiple city counts) so this won't work.

You can use COUNT and GROUP BY in the SQL to get something like

```
Country   State    Citiescount
Canada    state1      4
Canada    state2      3
USA       state2      2
```

etc, but you will have duplicates in the left hand column(s).

```
  SELECT country, state, COUNT(cities)
    FROM address_base
GROUP BY country, state
```

To get rid of the duplicates, loop over it to make an multidimensional array doing something like

```
$countries = array();
foreach ($results as $row) {
    if (!isset($countries[$row->country])) {
        $countries[$row->country] = array();
    }
    $countries[$row->country][$row->state] = $row->citiescount;
}
```

Alternatively, you can just echo the stuff instead. You can either get all the results in one go like this and loop over the whole set, or you can break it into smaller queries and do one per country or one per state. Be warned, however, that putting SQL in loops kills kittens (and DB performance) :).

Comment: @Matt...I have tried group by ...as it used used with aggregate functions...doesn't help much in achieving my target display. Moreover, two cities can have same name but different states in US..., I tried Group By zip-codes....but i found that a zip-code of US can be the same in mexico.  This creates a problem for me. Therefore i dropped that route.

Comment: GROUP BY should not cause a problem with duplicate values, as long as you get the clauses in the right order and include all of them. In the example above, I put country first, so you will get things grouped by that, then by state within the countries (one row for each state, even if the name is the same, as long as they are in different countries). I'm a bit confused as to what you are ultimately counting though. What do the numbers in brackets after the city names signify?

Comment: the number in the parenthesis after the city names gives me the total number of same city listed under the state..e.g:- in the above sample city 'apple' appear twice under the same city so - (2). This is what i am counting.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT Country, State, City From Address_Base ORDER BY Country, State, City') or die(mysql_error());

$countries = array();

// fetch results and build multidimensional array of city counts
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    if(isset($countries[$row['Country']][$row['State']][$row['City']])){
        $countries[$row['Country']][$row['State']][$row['City']] += 1;
    } else{
        $countries[$row['Country']][$row['State']][$row['City']] = 1;
    }
}

// loop over all countries
foreach($countries as $country => $states){
    echo $country, PHP_EOL, '{'; // output country start

    // loop over all states
    foreach($states as $state => $cities){
        echo $state, ' - '; // output state start

        $cityCounts = array();
        foreach($cities as $city => $count){
            $cityCounts[] = $city.' ('.$count.')'; // add all city counts to array
        }

        // implode all city counts and output it
        echo implode(', ', $cityCounts);

        // output new line
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }

    // output country end
    echo PHP_EOL, '}';
}
```

Comment: @Shef.....
 Would you please elaborate on this line: $countries[$row['Country']][$row['State']][$row['City']] += 1    --

Comment: @Tede: It keeps a counter for the city. If the array index with the city name exists it will increase the counter by one, otherwise the counter will start with 1.

Comment: Shef...thanks for replying...When i use this line: $countries[$row['Country']][$row['State']][$row['City']] += 1 ...it  gives me an error: 'Undefined index'.  removing the increment '+' , i am able to achieve all that i am targeting except the count of same cities in a state. Another thing that i find interesting  is the way you have coded for the dynamic multidimensional  array creation. I am glad to see it but i am not able to understand it. I searched the net a lot but there isn't much. Which book do i refer to or would you find some time to explain it for me?

Comment: @Tede: `Undefined index` is not an error, it's just a warning, ignore it. I built the multidimensional array based on the columns of your database. You can read about [arrays on php.net docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Or you can google it. If there is a line of code which is hard to understand for you, then let me know.

Comment: i have read about arrays and i understand that we use '=>' to define the keys and the values...but when we use this line of code... $countries[$row['Country']][$row['State']][$row['City']] += 1;  i find it hard to understand, that's why i asked....Could you please explain this line?

Comment: @Tede: You can do `$array = array('America' => array('Washington' => array('Seattle' => 1)));` to assign a multidimensional array to the `$array` variable. To modify the multidimensional array you do `$array['America']['Washington']['Seattle'] = 1;`. I am doing the second one, to modify the array, because the first one would reset the array all the time.

Comment: i understand now .... would there be any books multidimensional array modification if you know of any....another thing is i tried your code..it works...but the increment part (+) doesn't work....it gives me undefined index which u mention earlier to ignore but the problem is when i test my website...it gives that error the no coutries, states appear...but when i just remove the + operator ....everything works...it gives me countries , states and cities as i have targeted but since i have removed + increment operator...it doesn't count...this is the challenge that i am facing....

Comment: @Tede: I don't think there are such books specific for multidimensional arrays, but you should be able to learn them from any PHP book. I updated the code to get rid of that warning. Try it again.