# Php SQL query check (count ?) if they are listings depending of cities, states and countries

Tags: php, sql

I'm working on a hovered map of a country with hover css effect on the href links of the states. This link points to the listings from all the cities of this state.

I don't want the href link appears if there is no listing (no city).

My table is like:

table_content
contentid ----city ----- state ---- country

I need to check with an sql query:
If is there are contentid but depending if country, state and especially city are filled.

I don't need to show the results but only check or count if they are filled to echo my href link or no.

I hope this is clear.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Maybe it can help, it is a Joomla 1.7 site with Jreviews.

Here is my table:

I need to check, before displaying the link to the region Bretagne:

- If it exists cities (brest, quimper or lorient) inside all the departements of bretagne (here, finistere and morbihan).

----> If no, no link

----> If Yes, echo the link

|-----ville-----|-----departement-----|-----region-----|

|----brest----|---------finistere---------|----bretagne---|

|--quimper--|---------finistere---------|----bretagne---|

|---lorient----|--------morbihan--------|----bretagne---|

And almost the same for the link to the departement (i.e finistere)

I need to check, before displaying the link to the departement finistere:

- If it exists cities (ville) inside the departement of finistere.

----> If no, no link

----> If Yes, echo the link

All this row are depending together. By clicking on region, users should choice one, and then, the departements of this region appears, have to choice one, and then the cities of this departement appears...

Comment: Uhm...tried something so far?

Comment: Do you want to get number of contentids where $city, $state and $country are not empty?

Comment: Yes but I can limit to only one because if only one with city from a state and a country is filled, it must be a link. Exemple:
Paris from Ile de France from France
Versaille from Ile de France from France

Comment: Another exemple:

I have a france map. I would like to show the link to brittany ONLY if it has listing with contenid depending of the country (brittany), of the states ("finistere", "morbihan", "Ile et Vilaine", "cotedarmor") and the cities inside this 4 states (rennes, brest...).

So we will have to check that contentid has cities (something)
-Only in this states
- And only in this country (brittany).

Answer (score 0):

You may not want to "count" the registries as that would require a query for each state, as you are showing the state map you can start every state without link and then on a loop from a resultset using "select distinct states" or something that would list only states with registry in them, then you would activate state by state in a for-loop.

I hope you get the general idea, I can't write code right now.

Comment: Sorry but I don't really have any adea about your how to.

Comment: Spark, are you talking about something like that ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282522/grouping-cities-states-and-countries-in-mysql-php

Comment: Yes, but using "select distinct state from table_content" then when you get the result set there will be only the unique states (states won't repeat)

Answer (score 0):

You should use AJAX. Use `onmouseover()` event, and `getElementById()` to get parameters.

```
function check(city, state, country)
{
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else
      {
         xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
         if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200)) {

            console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
            if(xmlhttp.responseText == 1) DO SOMETHING;
         }  
      } 
      xmlhttp.open('GET','check.php?city='+city+'&state='+state+'&country='+country,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
}
```

In PHP script you check database for contentid.
`/*connect to database*/
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table_content WHERE city={$_REQUEST['city']} AND state=      {$_REQUEST['state']} AND country={$_REQUEST['country']}";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
    echo 1;
    else echo 0;` 
It's just an example.

Comment: I need to do that for all my country. I test the query and come back.

Comment: Don't get it. I  have an error: "Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource". Just trying the query

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM table_content WHERE city='".$_REQUEST['city']."' AND state='".$_REQUEST['state']."' AND country='".$_REQUEST['country']".'"` and $_REQUEST[] shouldn't be empty.

Comment: WOW, that way somebody can simply inject sql code into your system. You should escape those vars to avoid breaking stuff

Comment: `mysql_real_escape()` of course used. I think, it goes without saying

Comment: Well legiero, not sure of that. I'm really new with that. I've edited my first post to be more clear. I can't make your code work. Just need the query and then the href echo or not. Can you both check Spark and Legiero ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, what do you want.

Comment: Edited to try to make it clear. Hope that will help you. Check under "here's my table".